# Почему gulp-critical плохо генерирует стили?

Tags: gulp

Использую галп и этот плагин для критикала: https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical
Вот мой галпфайл:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const del = require('del');
const gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'); // для минификации
const rev = require('gulp-rev'); // для хешей
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const less = require('gulp-less');
const critical = require('critical');
const fs = require('fs');

const isDevelopment = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development';

gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return del('public/css');
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('less/all.less')
        .pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.write()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest('manifest-css.json'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});

gulp.task('critical', ['styles'], function (callback) {

    function generateCritical(fileName, path) {
        var options = {hostname: 'inabikari.cim'};
        if (path)
            options.path = path;

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (html) {
                critical.generate({
                    inline: false,
                    base: __dirname+'/',
                    dest: 'public/critical/'+fileName,
                    html: html,
                    minify: true,
                    width: 1300,
                    height: 900,
                    ignore: ['@font-face',/url\(/]
                });
            });
        });

        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request to '+ url +': ' + e.message);
        });

        req.end();
    }

    generateCritical('critical.css');
    generateCritical('critical-category.css', '/products/ups/inabikari/');
    generateCritical('critical-item.css', '/products/ups/line-interactive-ups/inabikari-ea200-400-2000va/');

    callback();
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'styles', 'critical']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['less/*.less', 'css/*.css'], ['build']);
});

gulp.task('dev', ['build', 'watch']);
```

Когда запускаю задачу build, какой-то из трех файлов генерируется пустым. Если отдельно запускаю задачу critical, все три файла генерируются правильно. В чем может быть дело?